# Django - filtering on related objects

Tags: django, filter

For my Django app I have Events, Ratings, and Users. Ratings are related to Events and Users through a foreign keys.  When displaying a list of Events I want to filter the ratings of the Event by a user_id so I know if an event has been rated by the user.

If I do:

```
event_list = Event.objects.filter(rating__user=request.user.id)
```

(request.user.id gives the user_id of the current logged in user) ...then I only get the events that are rated by the user and not the entire list of events.

What I need can be generated through the custom SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM `events_event`
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT *
  FROM `events_rating`
  WHERE user_id = ##
  ) AS temp 
ON events_event.id = temp.user_id
```

Is there an easier way so I don't have to use custom SQL?

Comment: [FilteredRelation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#filteredrelation-objects) objects might be of use to some people coming here

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `filter` method is for filtering which objects are returned based on the specified criteria, so it's not what you want here. One option is to do a second query to retrieve all ratings for given `Event` objects for the current `User`.

Models:

```
import collections

from django.db import models

class RatingManager(models.Manager):
    def get_for_user(self, events, user):
        ratings = self.filter(event__in=[event.id for event in events],
                              user=user)
        rating_dict = collections.defaultdict(lambda: None)
        for rating in ratings:
            rating_dict[rating.event_id] = rating
        return rating_dict

class Rating(models.Model):
    # ...
    objects = RatingManager()
```

View:

```
events = Event.objects.all()
user_ratings = Rating.objects.get_for_user(events, request.user)
context = {
    'events': [(event, user_ratings[event.id]) for event in events],
}
```

Template:

```
{% for event, user_rating in events %}
  {% if user_rating %} ... {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 6):

In addition to S.Lott's suggestion, you may consider using select_related() to limit the number of database queries; otherwise your template will do a query on each event's pass through the loop.

```
Event.objects.all().select_related(depth=1)
```

The depth parameter is not required, but if your other models have additional foreign keys it will limit the number of joins.

Answer (score 6):

The best practice would be

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch


event_list = Event.objects.all().prefetch_related(Prefetch(<related_name>, queryset=Rating.objects.filter(<criteria>)))
```

<related_name> = 'ratings' if:

```
class Rating(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, related_name='ratings')
```

This returns events and filtered ratings for those event objects

Answer (score 1):

To make best use of Django, you have to avoid trying to do joins.

A "left outer join" is actually a list of objects with optional relationships.

It's simply a list of Events, `Event.objects.all()`.  Some Event objects have a rating, some don't.

You get the list of Events in your view.  You handle the optional relationships in your template.

```
{% for e in event_list %}
    {{ e }}
    {% if e.rating_set.all %}{{ e.rating_set }}{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

is a jumping-off point.

Comment: rating_set is the manager which manages the relationship to rating, so it will always exist. Even if you did add a .count or .all to it, that would give you details for all ratings, not just those for the current user.

Comment: It's not my question :-) e.rating_set would be a django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager, so {% if e.rating_set %} would always pass. Trying to iterate it would give you TypeError: 'RelatedManager' object is not iterable. You would have to use e.rating_set.all to get your intended behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to do something like this.

```
events=Event.objects.filter(rating__user=request.user.id)
ratings='(select rating from ratings where user_id=%d and event_id=event_events.id '%request.user.id
events=events.extra(select={'rating':ratings})
```