# Annotate queryset with filtered related querysets which should be annotated as well

Tags: python, django, django-orm

```py
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()


class B(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()


class C(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()


class D(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A, related_name='set_of_a')
    b = models.ForeignKey(B, related_name='set_of_d')
    set_of_c = models.ManyToManyField(C, related_name='set_of_d')
```

I want to get a queryset that should replace the following function (may be pseudocode in some places):

```py
def get_queryset(name, list_of_c):
    result = list(A.objects.filter(name__icontains=name))
    for a in result:
        a.map_b_to_list_of_d = {}  # annotation
        for b in B.objects.filter(set_of_d__set_of_c__intersects_with=list_of_d):
            a.map_b_to_list_of_d.setdefault(c, []) += list(b.set_of_d.filter(a__name__icontains=name, set_of_c__intersects_with=list_of_c))
    return result
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django - filtering on related objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256325/django-filtering-on-related-objects)

Comment: No, I want not only to filter by related objects but annotate with them for further serializing without additional queries to the database

Comment: `prefetch_related` mentioned in one of the answers there performs the queries efficiently. It may not be one query but it will only be as many queries as the number of relations to be prefetched, so in your case 2 / 3 queries from what I understand.